# if else in regex

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression, which catches a first expression. If its not found, catch the second one.
The first one is a 2-4 long number with a following 'X', if it's not found, just catch the 2-4 long number without 'X'.

> foo bar 321 string 1234X and so on // catch 1234X

I found a short example [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) `(a)?b(?(1)c|d)` but i misinterpreted it.

```
(\d{2,4}X)?(?(1)(\d{2,4})X|\D(\d{2,4})\D)
```

It always finds the '321'. I tried several variations, but nothing works.

Comment: It really is a bad idea to try to implement some form of control structure in Regex.. The programming language should take car of that.

Comment: the most simple way is to write two regexps and cover it with `if else`

Comment: ok, i thought this short control can be done by regex. I mean, what is it good for, the if|else thing?

Comment: i dunno if for such coomplicated expression you should rely on regex

Comment: @Alex: The `|` is not `if else`, but rather `or`.

Comment: @felix yes i know, i meant if/else. i was confused...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
/(?| .*? (\d{2,4}X) | (\d{2,4}) (?!X) )/xs
```

(Quote and escape it properly before use.)

Note that it will match `1111X` in `1111111111111111111X`, and also if the number is part of "words". If you don't want that use something like:

```
/(?| .*? \b(\d{2,4}X) | \b(\d{2,4}) ) \b /xs
```

Perl demo:

```
perl -E "say join',','foo 123 bar 345X 44 33X' =~ /(?| .*? (\d{2,4}X) | (\d{2,4}) (?!X) )/xs;"
345X
```

Comment: `(?!X)` is not even needed in this case, added it just in case. It works due to the `.*?` in the first alternative, which makes sure any X numbers are found before checking the other alternation.

Comment: Nice one! Took me a while to understand exactly what it does, but I didn't read the question correctly either `:P`. You can maybe optimize by using `^.*?`. I'd also suggest `^.*(\d{2,4}X)|^.*(\d{2,4})` - it has two groups instead of one (which might be desired or not), but is considerably simpler in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just catch them all? By using alternatives with "|"?

Comment: i tried: `(?=(\d{2,4}w)|(?=\D(\d{2,4})\D))`. Just finds the first 321 without X